# Bing API error: no host given

Tags: django, python-3.x, bing-api

I am having an issue while trying to load search results from Bing. I have tried looking up a solution but I was not able to figure out what to do.
I hid my API key in my code snippet with `#api key here` but it should be correct.

Here is my code snippet:

```
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse

def run_query(search_terms):
    # Specify the base
    root_url = "https:a//pi.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search"
    source = 'Web'

# Specify how many results we wish to be returned per page.
# Offset specifies where in the results list to start from.
# With results_per_page = 10 and offset = 11, this would start from page 2.
results_per_page = 10
offset = 0

# Wrap quotes around our query terms as required by the Bing API.
# The query we will then use is stored within variable query.
query = "'{0}'".format(search_terms)
query = urllib.parse.quote(query)

# Construct the latter part of our request's URL.
# Sets the format of the response to JSON and sets other properties.
search_url = "{0}{1}?$format=json&$top={2}&$skip={3}&Query={4}".format(
    root_url,
    source,
    results_per_page,
    offset,
    query)

# Setup authentication with the Bing servers.
# The username MUST be a blank string, and put in your API key!
username = ''
bing_api_key = #api key here

# Create a 'password manager' which handles authentication for us.
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None, search_url, username, bing_api_key)

# Create our results list which we'll populate.
results = []

try:
    # Prepare for connecting to Bing's servers.
    handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

    # Connect to the server and read the response generated.
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(search_url).read()

    # Convert the string response to a Python dictionary object.
    json_response = json.loads(response)

    # Loop through each page returned, populating out results list.
    for result in json_response['d']['results']:
        results.append({
            'title': result['Title'],
            'link': result['Url'],
            'summary': result['Description']})

# Catch a URLError exception - something went wrong when connecting!
except Exception as e:
    print(("Error when querying the Bing API: ", e))

# Return the list of results to the calling function.
return results
```

The Error is: `('Error when querying the Bing API: ', URLError('no host given'))`

Comment: I suggest you have a debug flag that will re-`raise` the exception when active - so you know exactly what line is causing you trouble. Then, if it isn't clear, post here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the root url. It should read : https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search.